# Decent Free Linq debugger

Tags: linq

Is there a free LINQ debugger out there?  I am terrible at LINQ and the only way I am every going to improve is to have some simple debugger where I can debug the idiotic mistakes that I make with it.

Any advice?  A simple Google query nets bupkis free debuggers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is very good for debugging/creating LINQ queries